# Why array result is duplicated?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Can anyone help test this code and tell me what the error is?
The expected result is `01223658060102111111`. but it is duplicated like this

```
01223658060102111111012236580601021111110122365806010211111101223658060102111111
```

here is my code

```
<?php
ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5'); //without this file_get_content would not work
$saveURL = fopen("url.txt", "w");
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.carlist.my/used-cars/2592832/2004-toyota-camry-2-0.html");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


   $cont = $xpath->evaluate("//ul[contains(@class, 'list-contact')]/li");
   foreach($cont as $con){
    echo $con->nodeValue;
   }
```

Comment: try `echo $con->nodeValue."<br />"` to see if your echo in your foreach loop is actually running 3 times

Comment: use `unset($con)` after echo

Comment: Why do you need a `foreach` ?

Comment: Just add break; after echo

Comment: @ jitendrapurohit; Because I need all element inside li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line to

`$cont = $xpath->evaluate("//ul[contains(@class, 'list-contact')]/li");`

to

`$cont = $xpath->evaluate("//ul[contains(@class, 'list-contact')][1]/li");`

Comment: @ Haktan Suren; I want to insert 0122365806 and 060102111111 to 2 fields (contact1, contact2) in database. Could you pls give my any idea?

Comment: How can I split them to get result 0122365806 and 060102111111

Comment: You just need to modify the foreach loop like this
   $arr = array();
   foreach($cont as $con){
    $arr[] = $con->nodeValue;
   }
   $first = $arr[0];
   $second = $arr[1];

Answer (score 1):

> @july77: How can I split them to get result 0122365806 and 060102111111

```
   $arr = array();
   foreach($cont as $con){
    $arr[] = $con->nodeValue;
   }
   $first = $arr[0];
   $second = $arr[1];
```

Comment: What if the li element changing? Sometime it has 1, 2, and 3 or more than 3 contacts number? Can we solve this?

Comment: you can loop through $arr array but you can't handle the DB that way. You need better strategy to save the data in DB. For example you can save them in one filed delimited e.g. field1|field2|field3 etc... and you can use explode('|',$string) to access each individual item. Of course this depends how you want to implement it.